# why this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Tags: python-3.x

I want to replace null value in csv file with character 'O' and  my code is not saving  change values permanently in existing csv file.

```
ment_tagged = pd.read_csv("finalcolmnformat1.csv", sep =" ", encoding='utf-8')
ment_tagged=  ment_tagged.fillna('O', inplace= True)
for row in ment_tagged.iterrows():
    print(row)

A    B    C
g    a    NULL
d    b    YES
x    v     NULL
```

Expected output is  values are stored in same existing file like this:

```
A    B    C
g    a    O
d    b    YES
x    v     O


for row in ment_tagged.iterrows():
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: try `ment_tagged=  ment_tagged.fillna('O')`

Answer (score 1):

As you use `inplace=True`, `fillna` returns `None`. Shift to either:

```
ment_tagged = pd.read_csv("finalcolmnformat1.csv", sep =" ", encoding='utf-8')
ment_tagged.fillna('O', inplace=True)
for row in ment_tagged.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

or

```
ment_tagged = pd.read_csv("finalcolmnformat1.csv", sep =" ", encoding='utf-8')
ment_tagged =  ment_tagged.fillna('O')
for row in ment_tagged.iterrows():
    print(row)
```